# Got an Input to reshape is a tensor with 3368 values, but the requested shape has 2048 error while fine-tuning Roberta

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, huggingface-transformers, roberta

I have a csv file that has two input columns and one class with multiple labels which means I'm trying to do a multi-class classification using fine-tuned RoBERTa model. This is the structure of my csv file (`df`):

```
text                                             text2                                label
murray returns scotland fold euan murray named   People generally approve of dogs     3
concerns school diploma plan appeal              I'll have you know I've written      4
```

I followed this [HuggingFace](https://huggingface.co/course/chapter3/2?fw=tf) tutorial and saw that they use `DatasetDict` so I transformed my csv file into a `DatasetDict` structure by

```
train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2)

train_dataset = datasets.Dataset.from_dict(train)
test_dataset = datasets.Dataset.from_dict(test)

my_dataset_dict = datasets.DatasetDict({"train":train_dataset,"test":test_dataset})

"""
Received:
DatasetDict({
    train: Dataset({
        features: ['text', 'text2', 'label'],
        num_rows: 1780
    })
    test: Dataset({
        features: ['text', 'text2', 'label'],
        num_rows: 445
    })
})
"""
```

After this, I proceeded with tokenizing the data by doing

```
MODEL_NAME = "roberta-base"
tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)

def tokenize_function(dataset_x):
    return tokenizer(dataset_x["text"], dataset_x["text2"], truncation=True)

tokenized_datasets = my_dataset_dict.map(tokenize_function)
```

I kept following the tutorial and proceeded further like

```
data_collator = DataCollatorWithPadding(tokenizer=tokenizer, return_tensors="tf")

tf_train_dataset = tokenized_datasets["train"].to_tf_dataset(
    columns=["attention_mask", "input_ids", "token_type_ids"],
    label_cols=["labels"],
    shuffle=True,
    collate_fn=data_collator,
    batch_size=8
)

tf_validation_dataset = tokenized_datasets["test"].to_tf_dataset(
    columns=["attention_mask", "input_ids", "token_type_ids"],
    label_cols=["labels"],
    shuffle=False,
    collate_fn=data_collator,
    batch_size=8
)
```

I then initialize the model and compile it so I can fit later on, I have 5 classes so I set `num_labels=5`

```
roberta_model = TFRobertaModel.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME, num_labels=5)
roberta_model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-5), loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(tf_train_dataset, validation_data=tf_validation_dataset, epochs=3)
```

However the last line throws me an error that says

> Node: 'model_4/tf_roberta_model_7/roberta/Reshape'
> Input to reshape is a tensor with 3368 values, but the requested shape has 2048
> [[{{node model_4/tf_roberta_model_7/roberta/Reshape}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_113985]

I'm still learning this so I have no idea where this comes from, I went by the same steps from the tutorial I linked except they use BERT and have two classes, while in my case the only thing I changed is the `MODEL_NAME` and having five classes. Do you happen to know how can I fix this, what should I pay more attention at and how can I avoid errors like this in the future?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really an expert, maybe I'm wrong. However, shouldn't you use a model appropriate for your task (something like a `TFRobertaForTokenClassification` or `TFRobertaForSequenceClassification`, etc.). See the [documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v3.0.2/model_doc/roberta.html#tfrobertafortokenclassification) to see all of them.

As far as I know `RobertaTokenizer` has no head on top. Maybe that's the problem.